# Add data from one object to a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i writed this code ,

```
NSDictionary *json    = [responseString JSONValue];
    Status *statut = [[Status alloc] init];
    statut.flyNumber = [json objectForKey:@"flynumber"];
    statut.ftatuts = [json objectForKey:@"fstatuts"];
    statut.escDepart = [json objectForKey:@"escdepart"];
    statut.escArrival = [json objectForKey:@"escarrival"];
    statut.proArrival = [json objectForKey:@"proarrival"];
    statut.proDepart = [json objectForKey:@"prodepart"];
    statut.estDepart = [json objectForKey:@"estdepart"];
    statut.estArrival = [json objectForKey:@"estarrival"];
    statut.realDepart = [json objectForKey:@"realdepart"];
    statut.realArrival = [json objectForKey:@"realarrived"];

    [dataToDisplay addObject:statut];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

and i want to put the result statut object in a table view , each attribute in a line ( cell ) .
i don't know how to to . I writed this but they show them in the same line .

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSLog(@"1 ok");
    Status *statut2 = [dataToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"2 ok");
    cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",statut2.flyNumber,statut2.ftatuts];
    NSLog(@"3 ok");

    return cell;
```

Help please

Comment: Do you want each statut in one cell with multiple lines for each attribute? or do you want the each attribute of a statut in a different cell and then have separate groups for each statut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could have your Statut class return an array containing all of the properties you set from your JSON data. Then you can simply use the array to set the number of rows and the cell for each row.

Comment: There are 2 hours that i trie but i can't do it :/ Help please

Comment: When i want to make a method in statut who will return an NSArray , i have error "interface "NSarray" can not be returned by value..."

Comment: You could do it using an NSArray as @Jamie pointed out, but I wouldn't put the method in your Status class, because that is a model class and it would go against MVC. Instead, have your controller define a NSArray property and initialize it in your `-viewDidLoad:` method, e.g.: `self.statusAttributes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: statut.flyNumber, statut.ftatuts, /* ... */, nil];`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that allows you to configure the order in which your attributes will appear in your tableView:

```
// declare this enum in your .h file
enum {
    flyNumberRow   = 0, // first row in tableView
    ftatutsRow     = 1, // second row
    escDepartRow   = 2, // etc.
    escArrivalRow  = 3,
    proArrivalRow  = 4,
    proDepartRow   = 5,
    estDepartRow   = 6,
    estArrivalRow  = 7, 
    realDepartRow  = 8,
    realArrivalRow = 9

}
```

In your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method implementation:

```
// ...
// initialize the cell as you did in your code already

Status *statut2 = [dataToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

switch(indexPath.row) {
    case flyNumberRow:
        cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",statut2.flyNumber];
        break;
    case ftatutsRow:
        cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",statut2.ftatuts];
        break;
    // ... and so on for each case
}

return cell;
```

Evidently, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` must return `10`.

Comment: Thak you . If i will not find how to make an array i will trie it , it don't look very clean method .

Comment: You're right, encapsulating the data into an NSArray, is nicer. See my comment on @Jamie's answer...